# nn stops working when hidden layers get to big

Tags: python, neural-network

Whenever The number of hidden layer nodes for my nn is set to above 30 it outputs 1 for everything. But it works perfectly fine if there is less than 31 nodes in the hidden layer

```
import numpy as np

l1, l2, l3 = 0, 0, 0

x = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
y = [[1], [0], [0], [1]]

w0 = np.random.random((3, 50))
w1 = np.random.random((50, 1))



def predict(x):
    global l0, l1, l2
    l0 = np.array(x)
    l1 = np.array(sigmoid(np.dot(l0, w0)))
    l2 = np.array(sigmoid(np.dot(l1, w1)))
    return l2



def train(iterations):
    global w0, w1
    for iteration in range(iterations):
        error_2 = y - predict(x)
        delta_2 = error_2 * sigmoid(l2, True)
        error_1 = np.dot(delta_2, w1.T)
        delta_1 = error_1 * sigmoid(l1, True)

    
        w1 += np.dot(l1.T, delta_2)
        w0 += np.dot(l0.T, delta_1)


def sigmoid(x, deriv = False):
    if(deriv):
        return x*(1-x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))



train(100)
print(predict(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a fun one :)

Bad initialization. Your w0 and w1 are initialized with too large values. The larger the hidden layer, the smaller they should be. Google Xavier initialization.

Also, with your current initialization all coefficients are positive, no good, center them around 0.